# Native CSS nesting confusion

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the [Using CSS Nesting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting#appended_nesting_selector) guide on MDN, in the example section we have the following HTML structure:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="card">
    <h2>Card 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card featured">
    <h2>Card 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </article>
  ...
</div>
```

and CSS:

```css
.card {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  & h2 {
    /* equivalent to `.card h2` */
    color: slateblue;
    .featured & {
      /* equivalent to `.featured .card h2` */
      color: tomato;
    }
  }
}
```

My question is about this CSS line:
`/* equivalent to .featured .card h2 */`

How does it work? Since in the example the `.card` element is not a child of the `.featured` element, but styles are still applied.

My understand is that it should be like this:

`.featured.card h2`

I don't understand how nesting works in this particular case when we have several layers nested and `&` at the end of the selector.

Comment: That is not CSS. It looks like SASS a preprocessor.

Comment: @Paulie_D - That's perfectly fine CSS.

Comment: The [CSS Nesting module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/) using the `&` selector is currently in Working Draft, so while it is technically possible in native CSS now, it should not be used in production code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code comment line you referenced from MDN is wrong.

The `&` is equivalent to `:is(the-containing-selector)` so the innermost nested selector expands to

`.featured :is(:is(.card) h2)`

Which means "an `h2` element which has an ancestor which has class `card` and has an ancestor which has class `featured`". They can be the same ancestor.

```css
.featured :is(:is(.card) h2) {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="card">
    <h2>Card 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card featured">
    <h2>Card 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="card">
    <h2>Card 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </article>
</div>
```